# Is it possible to use more than two characters as points in a plot

Tags: r, plot, points

I am trying to plot points in a plot where each dot is represented by a number. However, it seems that the points can only be one character long, as you can see in the plot produced by the code below:

```
set.seed(1); plot(rnorm(15), pch=paste(1:15))
```

[image]

I wonder if there is any workaround for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
set.seed(1); plot(rnorm(15), pch=paste(1:15),type='n')
text(x=1:15,y=rnorm(15),label=round(rnorm(15),2))
```

[image]

another grid option  using `lattice` for example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:15,y=rnorm(15))
xyplot(y~x,data=dat,
       panel=function(x,y,...){
         panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
         panel.text(x,y,label=round(rnorm(15),2),adj=2,col='red')})
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the extra effort.  Though I think all Alex wanted was the numbers 1 through 15 at those points.

Comment: @NathanG It's always good to know additional tricks :) But yes, you are right. I only needed to know how to plot the numbers. Can't believe I didn't think of `text()`!